# .NET 6 worker service error when stopping

Tags: c#, windows, service, .net-6.0

Can someone explain this message and the Environment.Exit(1) statement? I'm testing out creating a windows service in .NET 6 and this advice is shown in the Microsoft example.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/windows-service

If the Environment.Exit(1) statement is included, when stopping the service, it returns the error "Windows could not stop the TestService service on Local Computer. Error 1067:The process terminated unexpectedly."

If I comment out that line the service stops without the windows error.

```
        // Terminates this process and returns an exit code to the operating system.
        // This is required to avoid the 'BackgroundServiceExceptionBehavior', which
        // performs one of two scenarios:
        // 1. When set to "Ignore": will do nothing at all, errors cause zombie services.
        // 2. When set to "StopHost": will cleanly stop the host, and log errors.
        //
        // In order for the Windows Service Management system to leverage configured
        // recovery options, we need to terminate the process with a non-zero exit code.
        Environment.Exit(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `Exit` is called in a `catch` statement, because the original author of the code snippet was trying to show you that within a Windows service app what's the standard approach to notify the user/machine administrators that an error occurred.

If you don't know what are "recovery options", I suggest you dig deeper into articles like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/rstmgr/guidelines-for-services).

In short, it is desired to see the error "Windows could not stop the TestService service on Local Computer. Error 1067:The process terminated unexpectedly", because we want to recover from such errors.

Comment: That's makes sense for service recovery. Using the Services.msc, right clicking on the service and selecting "stop" I should still get this error?

Answer (score 1):

I can't imagine the correct default behavior for stopping a service through Services.msc results in an error. And in my case, the OS was automatically restarting the service after a few minutes because of the error.

My quick and dirty solution was to catch the `TaskCanceledException` that gets thrown when stopping the service and just let the service quit without erroring. It would be better to figure out how to not throw the `TaskCanceledException` during a planned stop.

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    try
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Entering 5 minute processing window.");

            // Perform logic

            await Task.Delay(5 * 60 * 1000, stoppingToken); // Run once every 5 mins
        }
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Service async task was cancelled. Service will stop execution.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, "Error in Service: {Message}", ex.Message);
        Environment.Exit(1);
    }
}
```